# Two Basic Questions about Deck Transformations

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $p: \widetilde{X} \rightarrow X$ form a covering space over $X$.  Let

$$
D = \{\sigma : \sigma \text{ is an $\widetilde{X}$ isomorphism}\}
$$

form the set of **deck transformations** of $\widetilde{X}$.

**Question 1:** If $\sigma \in D$, in what sense is $\sigma$ an *isomorphism* beyond the fact that $\sigma$ is a bijective mapping?

**Question 2:** If $\sigma$ happens to fix a point of $\widetilde{X}$, this evidently forces $\sigma = id$ where $id$ is the identity mapping on $\widetilde{X}$.  Why is this so?

Answer (score 5):

1) A deck transformation, i.e., an automorphism of a covering space, is a homeomorphism $\sigma : \widetilde{X} \to \widetilde{X}$ such that $p \circ \sigma = p$.

2) Choose a basepoint $x_0 \in X$.  Suppose $(Y, y_0)$ is a connected pointed space and $f : (Y, y_0) \to (X,x_0)$ a continuous map of pointed spaces. Given $\widetilde{x_0} \in p^{-1}(x_0)$, then there is at most one map $\tilde{f} : (Y,y_0) \to (\widetilde{X},\widetilde{x_0})$ such that $p \circ \tilde{f} = f$.  (Such an $\tilde{f}$ is called a *lift* of $f$.)  This is a standard result in algebraic topology: it's Lemma 10.3 of Rotman or Proposition 1.34 of Hatcher.

Suppose $\sigma$ is a deck transformation that fixes a point $\widetilde{x_0} \in \widetilde{X}$.  We can apply the above result to show that $\sigma = \text{id}$.  Let $x_0 = p(\widetilde{x_0})$.  Then $\sigma$ is a lift of $p : (\widetilde{X}, \widetilde{x_0}) \to (X, x_0)$.  But the identity is also a lift of $p$, which implies $\sigma = \text{id}$ by the above result.

Comment: Hatcher chapter 1.3

Comment: In (1), doesn't that force $\sigma$ to be the identity mapping?

Comment: @user1770201 No, consider the universal covering $\mathbb R\to S^1$ and the homeomorphism $x\mapsto x+1$ on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: You missed some hypotheses on 2), most importantly that you can freely choose one $\tilde{f}(y_0) = \tilde{x}_0$ as long as $p(\tilde{x}_0) = f(y_0)$

Comment: @user1770201 No, that would only force $\sigma$ to be the identity if $p$ had a left inverse, i.e., if $p$ is injective.  But this is almost never the case.

Comment: @AlexZorn Yes, you're right I should probably be talking about pointed spaces.  I'll edit.

Comment: On (2), is the proof that $\sigma = id$ because if we let $(Y, y_0) = (\widetilde{X}, \widetilde{x}_0)$, that then $\widetilde{f} = \sigma$ (since $\sigma$ a homeomorphism on $\widetilde{X} \implies \sigma$ a continuous mapping on $\widetilde{X}$) so that the proof then follows?

Comment: I've edited my answer to clarify, but I think you have the right idea.